# What was the Order of the Phoenix's first headquarters?

Tags: harry-potter, order-of-the-phoenix

We know that Number 12, Grimmauld Place was the Order's HQ during the 5th and 6th books. Then it was moved to the Burrow. But what was their first headquarters? My only guess is the home of an Order member. [The definitive guide to the Order of the Phoenix and Dumbledore’s Army](https://www.pottermore.com/features/the-definitive-guide-to-the-order-of-the-phoenix-and-dumbledores-army-infographic) from Pottermore will give you a picture of the original Order. If you keep going down, you will see an interactive guide to each member. Hopefully, that will help.

Proof from Pottermore or the books is preferred.

Comment: Surely if the information from Pottermore you've linked to was useful to answer this question, you wouldn't need to ask it?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - I'm not seeing anything on that link that's especially useful in answering that question

Comment: I attached it so people could have a list of members. I was hoping that and others knowledge could help them solve the question.

Answer (score 4):

This image from the films shows that the original Order of the Phoenix met in full **at least once *in Grimmauld Place*** in 1981.

[image]

[image]

Note the distinctive panelled glass windows, long brown curtains and ugly striped wallpaper.

---

Moody states that there were members (including Dumbledore's brother) that he'd never met before this day which strongly suggests that they had no *centralised* headquarters, operating as a resistance from their own homes and places of work and only periodically meeting as a group to discuss strategy.

> ‘That’s Dumbledore’s brother Aberforth, only time I ever met him,
> strange bloke … that’s Dorcas Meadowes, Voldemort killed her
> personally … Sirius, when he still had short hair … and … there you
> go, thought that would interest you!’
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix: CHAPTER NINE — The Woes of Mrs Weasley</sup></sub>

Comment: The original Order wouldn't have met in the home of people who supported and agreed with Voldemort, especially when one of them was a Death Eater. That basically rules out Grimmauld Place, no matter what nonsense the films decided to include.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - Unless no-one was going to be at home

Comment: Grimmauld Place was not the home of any Order members (Sirius had left before he joined), so even if "no-one was going to be at home" they wouldn't have ever met there. You don't break into the houses of your literal enemies to hold your secret meetings, even if it's empty at the time.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - Take it up with the filmmakers. That's clearly Grimmauld Place. Maybe the house is completely empty during the summer months, making it a good place to have covert meetings.

Comment: Perhaps in the movie continuity Sirius's mother died earlier than she did in the books.  Or perhaps there's just more than one wizarding house with the same wallpaper and curtains - the colour scheme might be traditional amongst pure-blooded families, or something.

Comment: @Harry or it might somehow be related to Slytherin houses' colours

Comment: The decor is typical of an upper-class late-Victorian/Edwardian London town house/terrace. It only looks unusual now because Wizards (apparently especially the House of Black) are old-fashioned. Plus the filmmakers aren't going to bother with a whole new set just to take a photo.